# Getting error : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP

Tags: c#, email, outlook, smtpclient

I have a C# console application for sending mails over Outlook. But it is throwing an error 
"*The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [PN1PR01CA0115.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]"*. 
I have tried some available codes and solution but still getting this error.Even tried with port 25 but no luck. Please if someone can help.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        client.Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        mail.Subject = "this is a test email.";
        mail.Body = "this is my test email body";
        client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Port 25 is not secure.  For SMTP you need to go to your email server webpage and search for SMTP parameters.  Different email servers use different parameters.  You need a From address which is the same as the username.  This may be the reason for the error.

Comment: @jdweng I'm using From address same as username. And I couldn't find email server.

Comment: Are you getting same error after adding FROM?  Is mail server a website?  Do you have Outlook installed on your PC?  Outlook uses a Proxy Server.  I think error is due to you directly connecting to Outlook without going through the Proxy.  Also I Outlook is using your login credentials you have to use Default NetworkCredentials and not a username and password.

Comment: @jdweng yes getting same error after adding FROM and I do have Outlook installed on my PC. I tried without using username and password and using DefaultNetworkCredentials  but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It been over 10 year since I did research on SMTP.  Let me explain what I found when I did my research.  SMTP has three different modes of operation.  I think you are in the 3rd category

1) SMTP with Web Server : You connect to your email webserver using port 587 with Network Credentials contains your user name and password.  The From address has to be the same as the user account in the credentials.  Some websites still use non secure port 25.  Others use secure port 465.  So I  usually recommend checking email web server to get the SMTP parameters.

2) Outlook with Pop Account : An admin need to setup a Pop account in Control Panel : Mail Profile for each user.  Outlook is installed on PC.  When outlook is started it will connect to mail server using the User Mail profile.  So When SMTP is used you are also using the same User Mail Profile so you use Default Network Credentials instead of a Username and Password.

3) Outlook on Corporate Network with Outlook Server : Added security is used to prevent hackers from intercepting email.  The first time you use Outlook on a PC an installed is performed where the User Mail Profile is setup to connect to the Corporate Outlook Server.  The User login Credentials must be used (Default Credentials) when connecting to the Mail Server.  Port 587 is Port Forwarded to a Proxy Server.  So this prevents any SMTP message to go to a 3rd party webserver.  All email must go to corporate server.  When an email is sent credentials are verified by the Proxy Server by comparing the Default Credentials with the User Corporate Credential by checking with the Corporate Password Server.  I think you are failing this step.  After the Proxy verifies the credentials then the email is forwarded to the Outlook Server and is sent.

Comment: My situation is the third one, I tried to make DefaultNetworkCredentials = true but still getting error. So, what can I do so that Proxy checks this credentials.

Comment: Can you open Outlook from machine?  Usually you need outlook installer to setup the mail profile.  Once you have done that it really should work provided you are going to the same Outlook server that Outlook is using.  the only thing else is the port number.  See : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/server-settings-you-ll-need-from-your-email-provider-c82de912-adcc-4787-8283-45a1161f3cc3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us  also check the SSL section on the link.

Comment: Thee are 3 reasons you may be getting error 1) Port is blocked by Virus checker.   If Outlook runs from PC then this is probably not the case 2) You outlook server is using a different port.  Check with your MIS dept.  You may also check by running a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and check what outlook uses 3) SSL Encryption settings may not be correct.

Comment: I investigated and came to know that actually my Outlook account is Microsoft Exchange and that too in Cached mode. So, now I'm trying to code for the same.

Comment: Are you following instructions in link?  Did you check : In Outlook Web App, on the toolbar, select Settings Settings icon > Mail > POP and IMAP.

Comment: I tried to check through Web App but couldn't find anything like POP and IMAP under Mail but when I check through Outlook App installed in my PC, after clicking on File it shows Microsoft Exchange under my account name. I would have shared the screenshot here but I can't.

Comment: There are three types 1) Microsoft Exchange 2) POP 3) IMAP.  The default is Microsoft Exchange.  There should be a server name and/or URL.  My company have multiple server which are divided by first letter of last name.  You need to find the correct host to add to your code.

Comment: Yes I tried to find that but even when I click on account settings I couldn't found server.

Comment: Ash your MIS people.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. When all failed, I tried to do the same for the "FROM" account that had no administrator rights in Office 365. It worked right away.